# split file in bash after unescaped newline

Tags: bash, split, escaping

Given common bash-tools, it is easy to split a big file (in my case a MySQL dump and thus a TSV-file) into smaller parts using the `split` command. Furthermore, this command supports splitting a file after `n` new lines (i.e. `-l` argument). But this command does not distinguished between escaped and unescaped newline characters and thus might break a single table row into two incomplete parts.

Example (TSV with 2 columns)

```
cool    2014-12-15 17:31:00
do not censor it ...^M\\n      2016-01-24 22:33:00
watch out ari, you've got compeition! hahah     2001-12-05 19:11:01
Oh God, the poor guy!  xD\\nCan't wait to watch this!      2011-07-11 22:01:20
wish i could do that.\\n       2001-02-07 00:24:11
Funny! I will use this reason when I drink something in other houses    2015-06-10 12:20:00
```

As you can see, there are two columns (first contains the comment and the second the date), which are separated by an tab. I visualised just the escaped newlines, tabs and unescaped newlines are not printed. If you put these lines into a file and split it (e.g.,  `split example.tsv -l 1`) you will get 9 files, but there are only 6 comments (3 contain escaped newlines)! This is because escaped newlines are treated as regular newlines prefixed with a backslash. This is a huge problem for me, because splitting the file might lead to incomplete table rows in the output-files.

Is it somehow possible to ignore escaped newlines or does someone know another command which can do this?

Comment: Can you show us with some sample text

Comment: @Inian voila, I added an example. I hope this helps understanding my problem.

Comment: It would help if your sample text actually showed content with the linebreaks in question -- in your current sample, *no* line at all ends in a backslash literal.

Comment: I thought you mean "\" at the end of the line, this is "escaping new line". Your current example should have no problem wth `split`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will break the file every 20 lines (or whatever you set `n` to) but not on lines that end with a backslash:

```
awk -v n=20 'NR==1 || (c>n && !(last~/\\$/)){c=0; close(f); f="file" ++count ".out"} {c++; print>f; last=$0}' file
```

#### How it works

1. `-v n=20`

   This creates an awk variable `n` which we will use to decide when to split the file.
2. `NR==1 || (c>n && !(last~/\\$/)){c=0; close(f); f="file" ++count ".out"}`

   Every time that we need to start a new file, we (a) set the line counter, `c`, to zero, (b) close the previous file, and (c) define a name for the next file.

   We need to start a new file when (i) we are on the first input line, `NR==1`, or else when (ii) the line counter `c` exceeds the limit `n` **and** the `last` line did not end with `\`.
3. `c++; print>f; last=$0`

   This increments the line counter, `c`, prints the current line to file `f`, and updates `last` to the value of the current line.

#### Example

Let's try this test file:

```
$ cat file
text1   2014-12-15 17:31:01
text2\  
        2014-12-15 17:31:02
text3   2014-12-15 17:31:03
text4a\
text4b\ 
        2014-12-15 17:31:04
text5   2014-12-15 17:31:05
```

Now, let's run our command.  To keep the example short, we set `n=2`:

```
$ awk -v n=2 'NR==1 || (c>n && !(last~/\\$/)){c=0; close(f); f="file" ++count ".out"} {c++; print>f; last=$0}' file
```

After the command is run, new files appear in the directory:

```
$ ls
file  file1.out  file2.out  file3.out
```

The new files contain the old contents split every 2 lines except not split on lines ending in `\`:

```
$ cat file1.out
text1   2014-12-15 17:31:01
text2\
        2014-12-15 17:31:02
$ cat file2.out
text3   2014-12-15 17:31:03
text4a\
text4b\
        2014-12-15 17:31:04
$ cat file3.out
text5   2014-12-15 17:31:05
```